# Ionic 4 project having both cordova and capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying an Ionic project and I am happy with the Cordova community plugins currently available. Since my app is already using the Cordova is it okay to try out the capacitor and will it crash existing build files or have any mismatches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Capacitor to an existing Cordova project without fear.

If you do `npx cap add android`, Capacitor will create an `android` folder where it will put the Android native project.

If you do `npx cap add ios`, Capacitor will create an `ios` folder where it will put the iOS native project.

Both of them will detect the installed Cordova plugins and make the necessary operations to make them work in the Capacitor project (if they are compatible, not all are)

The Cordova native projects are inside `platforms` folder, so there is no risk of Capacitor breaking them.